# Как найти ± ближайшее значение в листе полученного из бд

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть `int a = 7661;` из бд получен `list<data>` имеющий в себе `string IdName` и `int Hech`. Как я могу сделать новый список или mySql запрос, чтобы  в нем Hech был: сначала значение `а`± 200 потом по убывающей до минерально, а в конце  от большего значение Hech до `а`+ 201.А в случае если нет значений `а`± 200 то от самого ближайшего

Comment: Это реализуемо длинным забегом на Linq, там довольно гибкое сортировки по методу `order`

Comment: Просто отсортируйте по возрастанию выражения `Abs(Hech - a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно может костыль, но рабочий

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Int32 a = 7661;
        Int32 plus = 200;
        Int32 minus = -200;

        Int32[] data = new Int32[10] { 7655, 7680, 7690, 7900, 7905, 7305, 7445, 7589, 7698, 7824 };
        List<Int32> data_n = new List<Int32>(data);
        List<Int32> data_min_max = new List<Int32>(data.Length);
        foreach (var i_n in data_n)
        {
            List<Int32> data_r = new List<Int32>(10);
            if (i_n <= a && i_n >= a || i_n <= a + plus && i_n >= a + minus) data_r.Add(i_n);

            foreach(var n in data_r)
            {
                Int32 min_l = Math.Min(a, n);
                Int32 max_l = Math.Max(a, n);
                data_min_max.Add(min_l);
                data_min_max.Add(max_l);
            }
        }
        Int32 count = 0;

        foreach (var n in data_min_max)
        {
            if (n.Equals(a)) count++;
        }
        for (Int32 i = 0; i <= count; i++) data_min_max.Remove(a);

        data_min_max.Sort();
        List<Int32> min = data_min_max.Where(x => x <= a).ToList();
        List<Int32> max = data_min_max.Where(x => x >= a).ToList();
        min.Sort();
        max.Sort();
        min.Reverse();
        Int32 min_n = min.First();
        Int32 max_n = max.First();

        Console.WriteLine($"max: {max_n}, min: {min_n}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

может, конечно чего то не учел!!!